# Sharing Google calendar via ANDROID ECLIPSE

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar

As i have already worked in creating events in a calendar in android.  I would like to know if there are any google apis or code available so that the I would be able to share my google calendars with any specific email id . Instead of going manually to settings and changing it in the google calendars.

Answer (score 0):

As for the Google Calendar access the best way is to use this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/.

Please note: there is not yet an official Android SDK API for the Calendar access.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no availability of such apis or codes released for the google calendar sharing functionality ??